# Can someone tell me what the issue with this code is?

Tags: java

```
public static int[] sortIntegers(int[] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < n - 2; k++) {
        //controls how many passes is needed to sort the entire array
        int test=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - k - 1; i++) {
            //controls the amount of swaps that is needed for each pass
            //ascending order
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
                //swap array[i] and array[i+1]
                temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
            test=3;
        }
        if(test==0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

public static void printArray(int[] array){
    for(int i=0; i<=array.length-1; i++){
        System.out.println("Element " + i + " is " + array[i]);
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to sort an array in ascending order and it doesn't appear to be working. Also my course for some reason says to create a new array of sortedIntegers but I dont get why you would want to do that when you can just alter the passed array. My friends tell me that creating a new array is the easier way but I feel like im not getting something....

Comment: You can't use `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: Missing braces (`{` and `}`) around the lines for swapping `array[i]` and `array[i+1]`.

Comment: "my course for some reason says to create a new array" -- because methods shouldn't modify their parameters

Answer (score 3):

These lines:

```
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
                //swap array[i] and array[i+1]
                temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
```

Don't swap `array[i]` and `array[i+1]`. It actually just assigns `array[i]` to `temp`. The subsequent two lines are executed unconditionally.

You need braces around them:

```
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                //swap array[i] and array[i+1]
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = temp;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't swap 'array[i]' and 'array[i+1]'. It actually just assigns 'array[i]' to temp. The subsequent two lines are executed unconditionally.

Make sure your code is like this...Putting braces around them.

```
if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
    //swap array[i] and array[i+1]
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[i + 1];
    array[i + 1] = temp;
}
```